# Is there a way to export data from a Spark dataframe directly to a Spreadsheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spreadsheet

In my work I use the Databricks tool to produce Scripts in Spark. However, a lot of analysis needs to be done in Google Sheets to facilitate the production of materials and sharing of insights.

I would like to know if there is a way to extract data from a Spark Dataframe to Google Sheets automatically, **without using toPandas()**, since the pandas function makes the script super heavy and sometimes takes many hours to run.

Comment: i found [this](https://index.scala-lang.org/potix2/spark-google-spreadsheets) on the internet

Comment: @samkart I could be wrong (english is not my first language hehe) but looks like this library is only used to read data from a spreadsheet. I want to insert new data in the spreadsheet from a spark dataframe

Comment: see the examples in the link. it suggests read and write both.